# Laravel 7.0: Login Error - These credentials do not match our records

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

This is my first big project with Laravel. I added a multirow delete function for my users table, it worked and logged me off and I haven't been able to log in again. Also all my routes aren't working.
i'm not really certain on what to do, i've tried to log in with other user details but the result is still the same. I've created a new user profile too.
Below is the code on the user blade file

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')

   <!-- Page Heading -->
    @can('user_create')
    <div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
        <h2 class="h3 mb-0 ">Staff</h2>
   
        <span class="d-md-flex d-sm-block left-side ">
        
        <a href="{{ route("admin.users.create") }}" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block button shadow-sm text-white py-2"> Add Staff</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    @endcan
    <!-- toolbar -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
        <div class="d-md-flex">
        <span class="d-flex mr-4">
            <span class="mr-2"><small>Sort</small></span>  <div class="dropdown arrow">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <small>All</small>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
            
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Name</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">No of ticket</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </span>
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block button-1 text-muted mr--3" id="DASR"> Layout off Staff</a>
        </span>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- main content column -->
        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="table-responsive px-1">
                        <table class="ajaxTable datatable datatable-User">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="align-middle">
                                        <label class="checkbox-container">
                                          <input type="checkbox" id="chkCheckAll">
                                          <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                        </label>
                                      </th>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3 "><small class="align-middle">Name <small></th>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="align-middle">Position<small></th>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="">Department<small></th>
                                      <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="">Phone<small></th>
                                        <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="">Email<small></th>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="">Assigned ticket<small></th>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="">Date Created<small></th>
                                    <th scope="col ml-3"><small class="">Actions<small></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($users as $key => $user)
                                    <tr class="rounded-3" id="sid{{ $user->id }}">
                                        <td class="align-middle"> 
                                            <label class="checkbox-container">
                                              <input type="checkbox" name="ids" value="{{ $user->id }}" class="chkBoxClass" >
                                              <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                      
                                        <td>
                                        <a href="{{ route("admin.users.show",$user) }}"><span class="d-block font-weight-bold">
                                              
                                              <img class="img-profile rounded-circle mr-2" height ="40" width="40" src="https://source.unsplash.com/QAB-WJcbgJk/60x60">
                                              {{ $user->name ?? '' }}</span></a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @foreach($user->roles as $key => $item)
                                                <span class="badge badge-info">{{ $item->title }}</span>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                          @foreach($user->categories as $key => $item)
                                          <div>{{ $item->name }}</div>
                                      @endforeach
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                          {{ $user->phone}}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle font-weight-bold">
                                            {{ $user->email ?? '' }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle">
                                          {{ count($user->tickets) }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="align-middle text-center">
                                          {{ $user->created_at ?? '' }}
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="dropdown no-arrow">
                                                <a class="dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                                  <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v fa-sm fa-fw text-gray-400 "></i>
                                                </a>
                                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right shadow animated--fade-in" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                                                 
                                                  @can('user_show')
                                                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.users.show', $user->id) }}">
                                                      {{ trans('global.view') }}
                                                  </a>
                                                  @endcan
                                                  @can('user_edit')
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('admin.users.edit', $user->id) }}">
                                                        {{ trans('global.edit') }}
                                                    </a>
                                                  @endcan
                                                  @can('user_delete')
                                                    <form class="d-flex" action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user->id) }}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('{{ trans('global.areYouSure') }}');" style="display: inline-block;">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                                        <input type="submit" class="dropdown-item" value="{{ trans('global.delete') }}">
                                                    </form>
                                                  @endcan
                                             
                                                </div>
                                              </div>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{ $users->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
@parent
<script>
    $(function () 
    {
  let dtButtons = $.extend(true, [], $.fn.dataTable.defaults.buttons)
@can('user_delete')
  let deleteButtonTrans = '{{ trans('global.datatables.delete') }}'
  let deleteButton = {
    text: deleteButtonTrans,
    url: "{{ route('admin.users.massDestroy') }}",
    className: 'btn-danger',
    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
      var ids = $.map(dt.rows({ selected: true }).nodes(), function (entry) {
          return $(entry).data('entry-id')
      });

      if (ids.length === 0) {
        alert('{{ trans('global.datatables.zero_selected') }}')

        return
      }

      if (confirm('{{ trans('global.areYouSure') }}')) {
        $.ajax({
          headers: {'x-csrf-token': _token},
          method: 'POST',
          url: config.url,
          data: { ids: ids, _method: 'DELETE' }})
          .done(function () { location.reload() })
      }
    }
  }
  dtButtons.push(deleteButton)
@endcan

  $.extend(true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    order: [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
    pageLength: 4,
  });
  $('.datatable-User:not(.ajaxTable)').DataTable({ buttons: dtButtons })
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
        $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
            .columns.adjust();
    });
})

</script>
<script>
$(function(e){
  $("#chkCheckAll").click(function(){
    $(".chkBoxClass").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
  });
  $('#DASR').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var allids = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=ids]:checked").each(function(){
      allids.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({
      url:"{{route('admin.users.massDestroy')}}",
      type:'DELETE',
      data:{
        ids:allids,
        _token: $("input[name=_token]").val()
      },
      success:function(response)
      {
        $.each(allids,function(key, val){
          $('#sid'+val).remove();
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
</script> 
@endsection
```

Comment: Check your database and see which records exist in users table. Probably when you called the multi row delete function it deleted all records or records with which you are trying to login.

Comment: In your javascript I can see a `massDestroy` route. Could you have not remove all the users and trying to login back with the user/s that you have removed? Check your database to see if the users exist.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was able to solve the issue by deleting the previous users table on my database and recreating it. Not really certain what the issue was, but it works fine now @DonKarnash

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a repo to share so we can see the full code base. I would say the problem is not to do with this page exactly. Would be interesting to know what the functionality is behind the route 'admin.users.massDestroy' too... this may have deleted something it should not have done.

Other than that I can only take a guess and possibly say the passwords aren't correct when logging in. Or something wrong with the cache. You could try clearing it.

Comment: I think something went wrong in my database, cause deleting the user table and recreating it seemed to solve the issue. Thank you for the response